# Summing only one value of list in case of repeat and transform it into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Stackoverflow, hello

I have a problem, which I almost solved, however, I have no idea in making last step.

So, in the initial list there are two almost identical elements `('Tomato', 3, 'PCS')` and `('Tomato', 2, 'PCS')`, in which only the middle parameter (quantity) is different and in the end it should be a sum of these two quantities. In the end I should sum 3 and 2. I will describe and it would be more easy to understand:

So, initial list is:

```
initial = [('Egg', 2, 'PCS'), ('Milk', 100, 'ml'), ('Tomato', 3, 'PCS'), ('Beef', 500, 'g'), ('Sweet pepper', 1, 'PCS'), ('Pita bread', 2, 'PCS'), ('Wine vinegar', 1, 'tbsp'), ('Tomato', 2, 'PCS')]
```

And in the end I should recieve:

```
{'Beef': {'measure': 'g', 'quantity': 500},
 'Egg': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Milk': {'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 100},
 'Pita bread': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Sweet pepper': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 1},
 'Tomato': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 5},
 'Wine vinegar': {'measure': 'tbsp', 'quantity': 1}}
```

But in the last but one line I recieve `'Tomato': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2}`, because the last element in the list just replacing the element with similar characteristics, not summing "quantity".

And the result I have is:

```
{'Beef': {'measure': 'g', 'quantity': 500},
 'Egg': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Milk': {'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 100},
 'Pita bread': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Sweet pepper': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 1},
 'Tomato': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Wine vinegar': {'measure': 'tbsp', 'quantity': 1}}
```

My code is:

```
for elems2 in initial:
    dinit = {'measure': elems2[2], 'quantity': elems2[1]}
    d = {}.fromkeys([elems2[0]], dinit)
    new_book[elems2[0]] = dinit
pprint(new_book)
```

Could somebody help me to solve the problem of summing "the quantity" - element inside the element of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple for loop:

```
result = {}
for item in initial:
    key, quantity, measure = item
    if key in result:
        result[key]["quantity"] += quantity
    else:
        result[key] = {"measure": measure, "quantity": quantity}

print(result)
```

This yields

```
{'Egg': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2}, 
 'Milk': {'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 100}, 
 'Tomato': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 5}, 
 'Beef': {'measure': 'g', 'quantity': 500}, 
 'Sweet pepper': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 1}, 
 'Pita bread': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2}, 
 'Wine vinegar': {'measure': 'tbsp', 'quantity': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

initial = [('Egg', 2, 'PCS'), ('Milk', 100, 'ml'), ('Tomato', 3, 'PCS'), ('Beef', 500, 'g'), ('Sweet pepper', 1, 'PCS'),
           ('Pita bread', 2, 'PCS'), ('Wine vinegar', 1, 'tbsp'), ('Tomato', 2, 'PCS')]

# count the measures by ingredient
counts = defaultdict(int)
for ingredient, quantity, measure in initial:
    counts[(ingredient, measure)] += quantity

result = {ingredient: {'measure': measure, 'quantity': quantity} for (ingredient, measure), quantity in counts.items()}

pprint.pprint(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Beef': {'measure': 'g', 'quantity': 500},
 'Egg': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Milk': {'measure': 'ml', 'quantity': 100},
 'Pita bread': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 2},
 'Sweet pepper': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 1},
 'Tomato': {'measure': 'PCS', 'quantity': 5},
 'Wine vinegar': {'measure': 'tbsp', 'quantity': 1}}
```

Comment: Is there a time benefit instead of using a for loop?

Comment: For this particular example probably not, for larger data perhaps.